# How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?

Tags: java, class, reflection, jar, load

I am trying to make a Java tool that will scan the structure of a Java application and provide some meaningful information.   To do this, I need to be able to scan all of the .class files from the project location (JAR/WAR or just a folder) and use reflection to read about their methods.   This is proving to be near impossible.

I can find a lot of solutions based on URLClassloader that allow me to load specific classes from a directory/archive, but none that will allow me to load classes without having any information about the class name or package structure.

EDIT:
I think I phrased this poorly.  My issue is not that I can't get all of the class files, I can do that with recursion etc. and locate them properly.  My issue is obtaining a Class object for each class file.

Comment: How can you load a class ignoring its fully qualified name? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: The answers below will let you locate the class files but, depending on the size of your project, it might be worth using [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). These will let you analyse the classes without loading them all into memory.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The following code loads all classes from a JAR file. It does not need to know anything about the classes. The names of the classes are extracted from the JarEntry.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar+"!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        continue;
    }
    // -6 because of .class
    String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
    className = className.replace('/', '.');
    Class c = cl.loadClass(className);

}
```

edit:

As suggested in the comments above, javassist would also be a possibility. 
Initialize a ClassPool somewhere before the while loop form the code above, and instead of loading the class with the class loader, you could create a CtClass object:

```
ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
...
CtClass ctClass = cp.get(className);
```

From the ctClass, you can get all methods, fields, nested classes, ....
Take a look at the javassist api:
https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/index.html

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old post (thank you for this answer btw, it works for me). However, `new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar+"!/")` caused a `ClassNotFoundException`. What did work for me was: `URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:" + pathToJar+"!/") };` Not sure why? Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Nice. You might wanna close the jarFile though? try { ... } finally { jarFile.close(); }

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: link is dead , someone fix it!

Comment: @RayanFar: fixed

Comment: - String.valueOf(".class").length() might be a bit more expressive than "- 6"

Comment: In some circumstances, you also want to add the parent class loader. `URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader())`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do you need to open or close the `JarFile`? There's a resource leak warning on the `JarFile` instance.

Answer (score 11):

List All the classes inside jar file.

```
public static List getClasseNames(String jarName) {
    ArrayList classes = new ArrayList();

    if (debug)
        System.out.println("Jar " + jarName );
    try {
        JarInputStream jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                jarName));
        JarEntry jarEntry;

        while (true) {
            jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry();
            if (jarEntry == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                if (debug)
                    System.out.println("Found "
                            + jarEntry.getName().replaceAll("/", "\\."));
                classes.add(jarEntry.getName().replaceAll("/", "\\."));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> To do this, I need to be able to scan all of the .class files from the project location (JAR/WAR or just a folder)

Scanning all of the files in a folder is simple.  One option is to call `File.listFiles()` on the `File` that denotes the folder, then iterate the resulting array.  To traverse trees of nested folders, use recursion.

Scanning the files of a JAR file can be done using the `JarFile` API ... and you don't need to recurse to traverse nested "folders".

Neither of these is particularly complicated.  Just read the javadoc and start coding.

Answer (score 2):

Came here with similar requirements:

> Have a developing number of service classes in some package, which implement a common
> interface, and want to detect them at run time.

Partial problem is finding classes inside a specific package, where the application may be loaded from a jar file or from unpacked classes in a package/folder structure.

So I put the solutions from amicngh and an [anonymous](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/reflection/recursive-method-used-to-find-all-classes-in-a-given-directory-and-sub.html) together.

```
// Retrieve classes of a package and it's nested package from file based class repository

package esc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;

public class GetClasses
{
    private static boolean debug = false;
    
    /**
     * test function with assumed package esc.util
     */
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            final Class<?>[] list = getClasses("esc.util");
            for (final Class<?> c : list)
            {
                System.out.println(c.getName());
            }
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scans all classes accessible from the context class loader which belong to the given package and subpackages.
     *
     * @precondition Thread Class loader attracts class and jar files, exclusively
     * @precondition Classes with static code sections are executed, when loaded and thus must not throw exceptions
     *
     * @param packageName
     *            [in] The base package path, dot-separated
     *
     * @return The classes of package /packageName/ and nested packages
     *
     * @throws IOException,
     *             ClassNotFoundException not applicable
     *
     * @author Sam Ginrich, http://www.java2s.com/example/java/reflection/recursive-method-used-to-find-all-classes-in-a-given-directory-and-sub.html
     *
     */
    public static Class<?>[] getClasses(String packageName) throws IOException
    {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        assert classLoader != null;
        if (debug)
        {
            System.out.println("Class Loader class is " + classLoader.getClass().getName());
        }
        final String packagePath = packageName.replace('.', '/');
        final Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(packagePath);
        final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        while (resources.hasMoreElements())
        {
            final URL resource = resources.nextElement();
            final String proto = resource.getProtocol();
            if ("file".equals(proto))
            {
                classes.addAll(findFileClasses(new File(resource.getFile()), packageName));
            }
            else if ("jar".equals(proto))
            {
                classes.addAll(findJarClasses(resource));
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Protocol " + proto + " not supported");
                continue;
            }
        }
        return classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]);
    }

    
    /**
     * Linear search for classes of a package from a jar file
     *
     * @param packageResource
     *            [in] Jar URL of the base package, i.e. file URL bested in jar URL
     *
     * @return The classes of package /packageResource/ and nested packages
     *
     * @throws -
     *
     * @author amicngh, Sam Ginrich@stackoverflow.com
     */
    private static List<Class<?>> findJarClasses(URL packageResource)
    {
        final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Jar URL Path is " + packageResource.getPath());
            final URL fileUrl = new URL(packageResource.getPath());
            final String proto = fileUrl.getProtocol();
            if ("file".equals(proto))
            {
                final String filePath = fileUrl.getPath().substring(1); // skip leading /
                final int jarTagPos = filePath.indexOf(".jar!/");
                if (jarTagPos < 0)
                {
                    System.err.println("Non-conformant jar file reference " + filePath + " !");
                }
                else
                {
                    final String packagePath = filePath.substring(jarTagPos + 6);
                    final String jarFilename = filePath.substring(0, jarTagPos + 4);
                    if (debug)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Package " + packagePath);
                        System.out.println("Jar file " + jarFilename);
                    }
                    final String packagePrefix = packagePath + '/';
                    try
                    {
                        final JarInputStream jarFile = new JarInputStream(
                                new FileInputStream(jarFilename));
                        JarEntry jarEntry;

                        while (true)
                        {
                            jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry();
                            if (jarEntry == null)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            final String classPath = jarEntry.getName();
                            if (classPath.startsWith(packagePrefix) && classPath.endsWith(".class"))
                            {
                                final String className = classPath
                                        .substring(0, classPath.length() - 6).replace('/', '.');

                                if (debug)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Found entry " + jarEntry.getName());
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    classes.add(Class.forName(className));
                                }
                                catch (final ClassNotFoundException x)
                                {
                                    System.err.println("Cannot load class " + className);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        jarFile.close();
                    }
                    catch (final Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Nested protocol " + proto + " not supprted!");
            }
        }
        catch (final MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return classes;
    }

    /**
     * Recursive method used to find all classes in a given directory and subdirs.
     *
     * @param directory
     *            The base directory
     * @param packageName
     *            The package name for classes found inside the base directory
     * @return The classes
     * @author http://www.java2s.com/example/java/reflection/recursive-method-used-to-find-all-classes-in-a-given-directory-and-sub.html
     * @throws -
     *
     */
    private static List<Class<?>> findFileClasses(File directory, String packageName)
    {
        final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        if (!directory.exists())
        {
            System.err.println("Directory " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist.");
            return classes;
        }
        final File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (debug)
        {
            System.out.println("Directory "
                    + directory.getAbsolutePath()
                    + " has "
                    + files.length
                    + " elements.");
        }
        for (final File file : files)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                assert !file.getName().contains(".");
                classes.addAll(findFileClasses(file, packageName + "." + file.getName()));
            }
            else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class"))
            {
                final String className = packageName
                        + '.'
                        + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6);
                try
                {
                    classes.add(Class.forName(className));
                }
                catch (final ClassNotFoundException cnf)
                {
                    System.err.println("Cannot load class " + className);
                }
            }
        }
        return classes;
    }
}
```