# How can get an instance from .class file in java

Tags: java, class, reflection, instance, .class-file

Frankly, I do not know even it is possible or not.
But what I am trying to do is just like below.

1. I made a class file from ClassFile.java via javac command in terminal.
2. Then I want to get an instance from .java file or .class file.
3. Next, I made another project in eclipse, As you guess this project path and upper file path are completely different. For instance, ClassFile.java/class file can be located in '~/Downloads' folder, the other hand, new eclipse project can be in '~/workspace/'.
4. So I read file which referred in step 1 by FileInputStream.
5. From here, I just paste my code.

   public class Main {

   ```
   private static final String CLASS_FILE_PATH = 
           "/Users/juneyoungoh/Downloads/ClassFile.class";

   private static final String JAVA_FILE_PATH = 
           "/Users/juneyoungoh/Downloads/ClassFile.java";

   private static Class getClassFromFile(File classFile) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("get class from file : [" + classFile.getCanonicalPath() + " ]");
       Object primativeClz = new Object();
       ObjectInputStream ois = null;
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(classFile));
       primativeClz = ois.readObject();
       ois.close();
       return primativeClz.getClass();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       getClassInfo(getClassFromFile(new File(CLASS_FILE_PATH)));
   }
   ```

   }

just like your assumption, this code has errors.
For example, it shows :

```
java.io.StreamCurruptedException: invalid stream header : CAFEBABE
```

this there any way to get object instance from .class file or .java file?

P.S.
 I wish do not use extra libraries.

Comment: Sorry for the filename that I referred in code is 'ClassFile.class', not 'HelloWorld.class'. I just tried to explain;;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar)

Comment: I think it can be in same manners but slightly different. Anyway, thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static final String CLASS_FOLDER =
        "/Users/juneyoungoh/Downloads/";

private static Class getClassFromFile(String fullClassName) throws Exception {
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
            new URL("file://" + CLASS_FOLDER)
    });
    return loader.loadClass(fullClassName);
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    System.out.println((getClassFromFile("ClassFile"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks:-) I finally invoke main method which is located in another .class file. Thanks a lot :D