# Java isInterface() does not return true for an Interface

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, I have defined an interface **MyInterfaceName** [MyInterfaceName.class]. This .class file is available inside a jarFile. 
 Using Java Reflection,  I am trying to use the method, `class.isInterface()` in this particular class, but it returns false.

Again, based upon the following references,

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/classes.html#modifiers
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isInterface(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isInterface%28int%29)

[ModifierValueLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier.INTERFACE)

I tried the following code:

```
int modifierValue = MyInterfaceName.class.getModifiers();
System.out.println(modifierValue)

boolean interfaceFound = Modifier.isInterface(modifierValue);
System.out.println(interfaceFound)
```

This `interfaceFound` returns only `false`. Also, `modifierValue` returns `17`, which doesn't fit anywhere in the [ModifierValueLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier.INTERFACE) I have provided.

But **MyInterfaceName** is an interface defined according to java standards.
I couldn't understand why it doesn't work.

Please help out. Thanks.

Comment: 17 = 16 + 1 (public final) - can you show the code?

Comment: You should use the class, not the name. (Hard to tell ifyou don't post actual code). Something like `MyInterfaceName.class.getModifiers()` should work.

Comment: @assylias: yes even i guessed the same. but what about the interface?   M.Deinum: from the very beginning am using the same what you have mentioned. I will post the code.

Comment: That 17 is very suspect - if it really is an interface then it shouldn't be `final`

Comment: @M.Deinum: As i am getting the class file from a jar file, am using this same methodology [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11016594/2530599) guy follows.  Once i get the jarEntry, i do the following: `boolean interfaceFound = jarEntry.getName().getClass().isInterface()`  But it returns false :(

Comment: That gets a `String` and not your class.

Comment: The value of `getModifiers()` is equal to 17 in case of `public final` class, or `public final` method or field. Post the `MyInterfaceName` definition, it is definitely not `interface MyInterfaceName`.

Comment: shouldn't it be MyInterfaceName.class.getModifiers(); ? You're calling the getModifiers() on the wrong object

Comment: Sorry. thats `jarEntry.getClass().isInterface()`.

Comment: am trying only `MyInterfaceName.class.getModifiers();` sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

My new answer is on this link.
http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.lang.reflect/Modifier/Java_Modifier_isInterface_int_mod_.htm

I have Implement the given exapmle at the link;

```
public interface MyInterfaceName {
    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;
}

import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class<?> cls = MyInterfaceName.class;

        int modifier = cls.getModifiers();

        System.out.println(Modifier.isInterface(modifier));

    }
}
```

This gives true. The coorect usage should be as at the link.

Comment: am using another way from Reflection. It gets the modifiers of that class. Please have a look at this link.                                      [Get the class modifiers using reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/classes.html#modifiers)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really how SO wants to work.

Comment: yes it returns an int value. This int would describe the type of modifier. For Interface it is 512. Yet it returns 17. :|

Answer (score 0):

Finaly got it :)

```
url = // Your jar file path
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(url);
Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader;
URL[] urls = { 
    new URL("jar:file:" + url +"!/") 
};
urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
       continue;
    }   
    String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);       
    className = className.replace('/', '.');            
    Class myClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass(className);
    if(myClass.isInterface()){
        System.out.println("Interface found - Name: "+ myClass);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all those who have replied :) and lol for the downvoter(s).