# How to override a java library in plugin development environment

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, polarion

I develop an application in a "special" plugin-development environment.

This environment needs to include some java libraries by default so that the created plugin-application can be exported and used successfully.

The problem is now that the plugin-environment comes with an old "javax.mail" library. It is not supported to override this library in the environment.

Of course it is possible to include the newer javax.mail library into my plugin-application but the library is not recognized and the old library is used.

**Question:**

Is it possible to force a Java Application to use a special included library which is using the same package and class names like a "native" library from a "plugin-environment"?

**What I have tried:**

I tried to rename the package files within the custom library "javax.mail" to "javax_external.mail" and to use something like this in my application:

```
javax_external.mail.Session session = javax_external.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
```

But I get the error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from javax.mail.Session to javax.mail.Session`

Comment: who ever uses the same packages in their own libraries should burn in hell... why does someone do this.

Comment: you will need your own classloader

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar ? Hmm...but how to map class and method names...