# Retrieve public fields from class

Tags: java, field

I want to use `getFields()` to retrieve public fields in a class but this is not working, the lenght of the array is always `0`. Do I need to use getters or `getDeclaredFields()` ?

```
Field[] fields = gameClass.getFields();
```

The class contained in gameClass :

```
public class Solitaire {
public Board board = new Board("Board1", "");
public Layout layout = new Layout();
public Player player = new Player();}
```

Here how the class is loaded into gameClass :
[Load a class in a jar just with his name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949333/load-a-class-in-a-jar-just-with-his-name)

Comment: Are you sure that `gameClass` has any public fields?

Comment: can you post your class?

Comment: Show us the definition of the actual class. And how you retrieved the gameClass variable.

Comment: I have added what you want

Comment: I recommend you to use gameClass.getName() in order to verify that you REALLY loaded the right class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the good name ...

Comment: Without full context it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the same thing -

```
Solitaire gameClass = new Solitaire();
Class gclass = gameClass.getClass();
Field[] fields = gclass.getFields();
```

And it's working perfectly for me :)

**Entire test class -**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Solitaire gameClass = new Solitaire();
    Class gclass = gameClass.getClass();
    Field[] fields = gclass.getFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("field: " + fields[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Solitaire {

    public Solitaire a;
    protected String b;
    public String c;

    public Solitaire() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the fact that I don't declare a constructor in solitaire a problem ?

Comment: no, getFields() is supposed to return all public fields on the class (not private or package-protected though). It does not need a constructor which is for constructing object instances of the class, it needs only access to the class object.

Comment: Can you try using getDeclaredFields() and see what that returns?

Comment: Constructor declaration is not required actually. Are you sure, at least one field is public?

Comment: It works, I don't know why this was not working, but it work and I have a new problem ...

Comment: (surprising emoticon) Good luck :)