# Using a Jar file inside a java application

Tags: java, jar

I've tried searching through java documentation. I could not find anything on opening a jar file inside of a java application. To further explain what I`m trying to do I will use an example. MinecraftForge has a folder where all of the mods get loaded from using jar files.

I would like to be able to put jar files inside a folder that will be used by the application. Is this possible and could somebody point me in the right direction.

Comment: Form a question and show us what you tried.

Comment: are you using any ide?

Comment: I'm using Intellij Idea

Comment: The folder would have to be specified as part of the classpath when the program launches; otherwise, you could use a `URLClassLoader` to specify the local URL to the JAR file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar)

Comment: Might do It I'll try it when I get a chance thanks

Comment: THANKS! Shotgun Ninja works exactly as I hoped.