# Using all classess from given directory

Tags: java

I need to call the same method on every class in given directory(they all implement the same interface) having files with .class or .java extension. Is it possible to achieve? How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar)

Comment: Loading all classes from your interface (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically) and compare them to the directory list (or inverse).