# Java Load Class Dinamically in ChildClassLoader related to SystemClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a java web application that comes wiht a abstract class, (lets call it `ClassA`) deployed on an application server. This java web application also loads classes from external jars dinamically, by using the approach on [this question's accepted response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar).

Everything works fine, until I get to load a class (call it, `ClassB`) that extends from `ClassA`. I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClassA` error message on my SysOut, pointing to the line that loads the class: `urlClassLoader.loadClass(className);`.

I assumed I wouldn't have a problem, since when I call `URLClassLoader.newInstance()`, it gets created [from the default parent class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#newInstance%28java.net.URL[]%29), which I suppose should be the `SystemClassLoader`, which I assume contains the WebApp classes.

- Is any of my assumptions wrong?
- How can I load a class from an external Jar, which happens to extend from a parent class loaded in the WebApplication classloader?

I tried changing the deployment configuration of my WebApp from parent first to parent last and got the same error. I also tried doing a `Class.forName("ClassA")` before executing the `URLClassLoader.loadClass("ClassB")` line but got the same error again.

Comment: can you just pass ClassA.getClassLoader as a parent parameter to your custom class loader?

Comment: Well, that actually solved my problem! That means, my URLClassLoader doesn't check in the SystemClassloader when I do a Class.forName()? Can I somewhat "merge" the two classloaders?

Comment: I suspect that your ClassA was loaded by webapp classloader (which is child of system classloader) and your UrlClassLoader is a child of system class loader also, so they are two leafs of the same parent. Not 100% sure because it depends on a web container you use.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! I would suggest to post that as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ClassA` is loaded by some container's `WebAppClassLoader` which is a child of `SystemClassLoader`. Your custom `URLClassLoader` is a child of `SystemClassLoader` too and that's the reason why `ClassB` doesn't "see" `ClassA`.

To solve the problem, `ClassB` should be loaded by `WebAppClassLoader` or its child, it can be achieved with:

```
ClassLoader webAppCL = ClassA.class.getClassLoader();
URLClassLoader myCL = new URLClassLoader(urls, webAppCL);
```