# Solr ClassCastException with custom TokenFilterFactory

Tags: java, solr, classcastexception, solrj

I've got the problem with core creation with Solr 6.3.0
I've got class extending lucene's TokenFilterFactory

```
public class CustomTokenFactory extends TokenFilterFactory
```

In solr core solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/target/" regex="myjar-1.0.0.jar" />
```

When I'm trying to start solr - the ClassCastException occurs

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "MyAnalyser": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: class com.myjar.CustomTokenFactory 
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:182)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:491)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: class com.myjar.CustomTokenFactory 
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:182)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.readAnalyzer(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:152)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.myjar.CustomTokenFactory 
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:540)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$2.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:341)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader$2.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:334)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:152)
    ... 19 more
```

My pom contains following solr\lucene libs

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jwordnet/jwnl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jwordnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwnl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4_rc3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for wikipedia cleanup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-maxent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-maxent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-uima -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-uima</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-analysis-extras -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-analysis-extras</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-benchmark -->
    <!--  for indexing wikipedia -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-benchmark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-benchmark</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What can be cause of such error in solr? My first idea was lib versions mismatch - but everywhere is *-6.3.0.jar

Dependency tree is like this:

```
 +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.jwordnet:jwnl:jar:1.4_rc3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-tools:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-maxent:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-uima:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-analysis-extras:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-icu:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-kuromoji:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-morfologik:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-phonetic:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-smartcn:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-stempel:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-classification:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-expressions:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.facebook.presto:presto-parser:jar:0.122:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.5.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:56.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- io.airlift:slice:jar:0.10:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.5.1-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.8.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.8.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.8.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.2.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-fsa:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-polish:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.carrot2:morfologik-stemming:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.8.v20160314:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.noggit:noggit:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-benchmark:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:jar:6.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:6.3.0:provided
[INFO] \- edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:3.9.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- de.jollyday:jollyday:jar:0.4.9:compile
[INFO]    +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:jar:0.23:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0359:compile
[INFO]    +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438:compile
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the import path for `TokenFilterFactory` in your code example? Another option is that you've ended up [bundling a version of the TokenFilterFactory class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044932/classcastexception-thrown-when-calling-assubclass-from-separate-jar) yourself and have conflicting class names (i.e. they're referencing different classes).

Comment: The import is `import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;`; IDEA shows that this class is in `lucene-analyzers-common:6.3.0`.  I tried to build mvn dependency tree to find any lib conflicts, but there is no other libs containing such class

Comment: You should post your entire Pom.xml file. On the other hand try investigating in the other dependencies. In my experience such errors can happen when you have multiple dependencies of the same library.

Comment: @freedev I agree with you, that it is dependencies problem, but I can't find where the conflict occurs. Added to question full dependencies list and maven dependency tree

Comment: I tried to exclude `lucene-analyzers-common` from all dependencies and add it explicitly - same result

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
It's not related to class loading, but to `schema.xml`.
I defined my CustomTokenFactory in `<tokenizer>` tag instead of `<filter>` tag. And solr was trying to do `asSubclass` to `TokenizerFactory`.
The remote debugging helps a lot in this case.