# Load dynamic library java that inherit interface

Tags: java, dynamic, jar, load, shared-libraries

I want to load dynamic library where classes inherit from an interface/abstract class on my core project, so I can load my classes at runtime and use it. How can i do that ?

Example:

Core: `ITrigger (interface)`

Library: `{MyTriggerOne extends ITrigger} {MyTriggerTwo extends ITrigger}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a class/library dynamically use Class.forName('class name') method to load.

Comment: Yes, but the class name are not the same, so how could i load classes dynamically without the classname known

Comment: Without knowing the classname it will be difficult. One solution is to load the entire library/jar using Class.forName and then using reflection identify the class which implements your interface, then create an instance of that class.

Comment: If i load the entire jar using Class.forName, my jar become a "class" and my classes inside the jar becomer "inner classes" ?

Comment: use this solution to load your class from jar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar

Answer (score 0):

Java's SPI(Service Provider Interface) libraries allow you to load classes dynamically based on the interfaces they implement, that can be done with the help of META-INF/services.

You can create a interface like

```
package com.test.dynamic;
public interface ITrigger {
    String getData();
    String setData();
}
```

you can use the `ServiceLoader` class to load the interface like below code

```
ServiceLoader<ITrigger> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ITrigger.class);
```

then you can perform all the operation on it.
If you have some other implementing classes on your classpath, they register themselves in META-INF/services.
you need to create a file in META-INF/services in your classpath with  the following properties

1. The name of the file is the fully qualified class name of the
   interface, in this case, it's com.test.dynamic.ITrigger
2. The file contains a newline-separated list of implementations, so
   for the example implementation, it would contain one line:
   com.test.dynamic.impl.SomeITriggerImplementation class.

Comment: I must register the implementing classes in the main JAR program or on the library JAR ?

Comment: you need to create a file in META-INF/services in your classpath with some property like

Comment: I must create my META-INF here ?
-> src/main/resources/META_INF/

Comment: ya or you can use some build tolls like  Maven, Ant, etc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and I used the library [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Very simple code snippet:

```
public Set<Class<? extends ITrigger>> getITriggerClasses() {
    final Reflections reflections = new Reflections("package.where.to.find.implementations");
    return reflections.getSubTypesOf(ITrigger.class);
}
```

Then you can use the method `Class::newInstance` to create the `ITrigger`(s).
This is a very simple example, there are several options to initialize the `Reflections` class (not only with one package name).