# Java, Load classes from JAR to use them later

Tags: java, reflection, load

I have a problem loading class from JAR file.

I can load them with URLClassLoader using a JarFile etc etc [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016392/5112735); but if later in code I try to instantiate them with reflection:

`Object obj = Class.forName(className).newInstance()`

I get a ClassNotFoundException. 
Can I dinamically load a class to use them later, when I need them, just like classes in ClassPath? 
Thank you!

Comment: I think you should call newInstance() on the Class instance you already loaded with the code you are referencing or make sure the jar file is on the classpath

Comment: It seems to be a class path issue. The exception is likely coming from the forName call. Are you sure the class you are trying to instantiate is in the class path?

Comment: Class i'm trying to instantiate is not in classpath, it is in an external jar file

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide class loader to `Class.forName` method - as otherwise it will look in this same class loader as your class is in.
`Object obj = Class.forName("name", true, loader).newInstance()` .

But you can't just load a class and then use it in your code like `MyLoadedType` - as here java does not know where to look for that class, unless you will ensure that your code and loaded code is in this same class loader - you can do this by running all your code from custom class loader that allows for adding new sources in runtime. (`URLClassLoader` allows for this but method is protected - so you need to extend it and make it public, in java 8 system class loader is also `URLClassLoader` - but this was changed in java 9) .

But you can operate on that code using reflections like I showed you.