# Load classes in Spring before component scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a situation a work where we have several jar filed in npm packages.  If I add all the paths to the classpath before running my spring mvc app, it works fine.

But we want a "modular" way of doing this.  IE,  I don't know of all the packages that may or may not be there at runtime.  I have a base folder,  and I can easaly do a recusive file scan for all jar files,  but how do I then load them before the component scan so everything is wired in correctly?  I have this standard in my base Application class:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

I assume I have to do something in my main() before I call run(),  but im not sure what to do.

**EDIT** I have been trying to get this to work, and forgot to mention that this is a .war file in a tomcat container,  and I don't think the main() method is being called.

Comment: Perhaps this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar . You can repeat same approach for each jar you want to load early in tour `main`