# How do you load a class that is not in the classpath & is in a jar?

Tags: java

I want to load a class that is in a jar.

I already tried to just load the class using this code:

```java
URL dirUrl = jarFile.toURL();
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {dirUrl}, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<?> clazz = ucl.loadClass(mainClass);
ucl.close();
```

I get an exception that it couldn´t find the class:

```py
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.api.main
        at net.al.Main.onEnable(Main.java:39) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:741) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:535) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:627) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:412) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:375) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.api.main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at net.al.addon.AddonLoader.loadAddons(AddonLoader.java:129) ~[?:?]
        at net.al.Main.onEnable(Main.java:36) ~[?:?]
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: either the jar file location is incorrect, or the class name is incorrect (case sensitive)

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with adding the jar to the classpath.
Code to at file to jar path:

```java
public static void addURLToClassPath(URL url) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
    {
        URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class clazz = URLClassLoader.class;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { url });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check net.api.main does it exist

or check variable  jarFile  and  mainClass